# How can/could he walk away from his brother? - What are the differences?

Tags: meaning

**Example 1**

> How **can** he walk away from his brother?

**Example 2**

> How **could** he walk away from his brother?

What are the differences?

**Could** is a one-time past?

**Can** is something still going on?

Is it an exclamation of disbelief, right?

Answer (score 3):

**How could he walk away from his brother?** is *either* an exclamation of disbelief (that he did so at some time in the past) *or*, in a narrative, an acknowledgement that of course he couldn't (so he didn't).

The same applies to **How can he walk away from his brother?** with reference to an incident in the present - disbelief that he is doing so, or acknowledgement that he has no choice but to stay with his brother.